# jQuery vector-map plugin: get dimensions of country

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm using the jq-plugin vector-map to show a map where coutries are highlighted on mouseover.
When a country is clicked, it should zoom in to it.
My problem is that I couldn't find out how to get the dimensions of the clicked country (min/max x/y coordinate), so that I can properly scale it to cover the available screen area.

The input data from which the map is created is an array with elements having the following format:

```
'lu': { 'lock':1, 'type':'country', 'name': 'Luxembourg', 'path': 'M233.7,335.91l-2.56,3.47l-1.08,5.64 c0.16,0.02,0.31,0.05,0.48,0.05c1.96-0.08,3.24-0.59,4.86,0c0.02,0.01,0.03,0.01,0.04,0.02l0.47-3.6L233.7,335.91z' }
```

I've no previous experience with svg or with this plugin, so maybe there's an obvious solution I don't see.

Suggestions for alternative solutions not relying on this jq plugin are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If `path` is a variable referencing the path element then `path.getBBox()` returns an object on the following the form:

```
{
    x      : ...
    y      : ...
    width  : ...
    height : ...
}
```

Where `x` and `y` represent the top-left corner. For zooming you can set the `viewBox` attribute on the wrapping svg element to `viewBox="x y width height"`. I mean something like this:

```
svg  = document.querySelector('svg');
path = svg.querySelector('path');
box  = path.getBBox();
svg.setAttributeNS(null, 'viewBox', box.x +' '+ box.y +' '+ box.width +' '+ box.height);
```

Comment: The plugin uses VML instead of SVG as fallback for IE <= 8. Am I right in assuming that the described method doesn't work in that case?